# Splitting a line on the basis of pattern after traversing certain number of lines using Unix/Linux commands

Tags: linux, shell, unix, amazon-ec2, command-line

I have a file of 100469448 number of lines. I want to split the file into two in such a way that after parsing through almost half number of lines, it looks for the " </ abc> and one empty line" and splits from the next line.

Sample file

```
<abc>
d
f
.
.
.
</abc>
x
d
w            (line number 50469450)
</abc>

<abc>
w
d
s
etc
```

Above file should be split into two files, file 1 (splitting after traversing almost half of file)

```
<abc>
d
f
.
.
.
</abc>
x
d
w                          (line number 50469450)
</abc>
```

and file2

```
<abc>
w
d
s
etc
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to put those 2 outputs to different files ?

Comment: You could use [`csplit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) to split every `<abc>` block into a separate file, then reassemble those files.

Comment: @Emil yes, I want to split them in two different files, but after traversing almost half number of lines

Comment: @BenjaminW.  C split wont let me split after certain number of lines

Comment: @Runjhun You can use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: You'd have to count lines and reassemble accordingly. Or you could `split` in half, then `csplit` the second half on the pattern and reassemble the first two files.

Comment: Do I understand this right: you want to split into two files, but keep all `<abc>` blocks together and keep the block that would be split in the first file?

Comment: Is it important that the break is at "`</abc>` + blank line", or could also be "before `<abc>`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have a file with thousands of <abc>...</abc> blocks.
I want to split it into two files such that  data inside <abc> ..</abc> blocks dont get split, hence i want it to break after </abc>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps with [`split`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) and [`csplit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html).

Assuming your input file looks like this:

```
$ cat infile
<abc>
a
b
c
</abc>

<abc>
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
</abc>

<abc>
n
o
</abc>

<abc>
p
q
r
</abc>
```

First, we split into two files:

```sh
split -l $(($(wc -l < infile) / 2 + 1)) infile
```

`split -l n` splits into files with *`n`* lines each. We want to get two files, so we take the number of input lines and split it by half: `$(wc -l < infile) / 2`. This is integer division, so for an odd number of input lines (say, 11), we'd end up with three files (5, 5, and 1 lines); to avoid that, we add 1.

We now have these two files:

`xaa`:

```
<abc>
a
b
c
</abc>

<abc>
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
```

`xab`:

```
l
m
</abc>

<abc>
n
o
</abc>

<abc>
p
q
r
</abc>
```

We want the first part of `xab` to become part of the first file. For this, we use `csplit` to split on a pattern:

```sh
csplit xab '/<abc>/'
```

This splits `xab` into two new files:

`xx00`:

```
l
m
</abc>
```

`xx01`:

```
<abc>
n
o
</abc>

<abc>
p
q
r
</abc>
```

The two files we want are `xaa` plus `xx00`, and `xx01`. We concatenate and rename:

```sh
cat xaa xx00 > file1
mv xx01 file2
```

and clean up:

```sh
rm xaa xab xx00
```

---

#### Remarks

GNU `split` has an option to prescribe the number of files to split into:

```sh
split -n2 infile
```

or, to prevent splitting lines:

```sh
split -n l/2 infile
```

but the output files might have varying numbers of lines since the split is by size in bytes, rather than lines.